# ZeroMQ as apache dynamic library + PHP

Tags: php, apache, zeromq

Do I really need ZMQ.so for messaging using php and websockets?
I am developing a wordpress plugin, but it is going to be installed on a shared hosting, so I don't want to have additional dynamic libraries on the server.

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to be installed by users onto servers that may not have ZMQ installed, then you're going to have to use something other than ZMQ.  Keep in mind, ZMQ.so is just the PHP bindings, you also have to have the base ZMQ library installed before those bindings will work - so it's not a good candidate for a shared hosting.  I believe [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) provides options for directly using websockets without using the ZMQ engine on the server side, and without any additional libraries, but I haven't delved too deeply to confirm that for certain.

Comment: Unfortunately Ratchet is the one that requires ZMQ to work, its second example is exactly what I need to implement. I am looking at other alternatives right now like Server Side Events.

Comment: You may be right - my only exposure to Ratchet is by answering ZMQ questions here, but my impression was that Ratchet had a more traditional socket approach but that it *also* implemented ZMQ for PHP as an additional feature.

Comment: Yes... the only problem I am having with this is the server part that needs to be run from (the file that starts from /bin/ in the Ratchet example). I maay have some luck installing ZMQ.so for Apache/PHP5.

Comment: Can you link to the example you're using?

Comment: That helps to clarify what you're after. Yes, to use ZMQ to enable a simpler Ratchet integration as in your chosen example, you'll need to install both the ZMQ library and the ZMQ.so Apache module. If you just want straight websockets, you can use Ratchet without ZMQ. There's also [PHP Websockets](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets) if you prefer a different API. [Server Side Events](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource) appears not to be supported under any version of IE, and likely will not be given its lack of popularity. And you've always got more traditional AJAX polling methods.